# How to use Java Android Beam to beam message from PC TO Phone?

Tags: java, nfc, ndef, nfc-p2p, android-beam

Basically, I am asking how to reverse the Android Beam program, which sends a message from an Android Phone that has NFC capabilities, to eclipse on my PC via an NFC reader. I have no idea where to start. I CAN FIND NO DOCUMENTATION ON WHERE TO GET STARTED ONLINE, OTHERWISE I WOULD USE THAT INSTEAD OF POSTING MY QUESTION HERE.

Answer (score 3):

Android Beam uses the SNEP protocol over the LLCP communication link between 2 Android NFC devices. So you need an LLCP implementation and a SNEP layer on top of that. A project that provides this (and more) is [nfcpy](http://nfcpy.readthedocs.org/).